# Split a string for values outside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string - `'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),'`

I want to split it so that I get all the values outside the parenthesis split by comma.

OUTPUT - `A B C D E F`

I am trying to do this in JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: And have you tried any thing yet?

Comment: _"I am trying to do this in JavaScript"_ So show us the attempts!

Comment: So far just - str.split(/,/).. I am obviously looking for the regex that would substitute /,/. I am pretty new to regex.

Comment: You have a string, but do you know all possible structures for that string?  is `A("foo),bar("), B(...` valid?  If not can you define the format?  If you can, that's half the battle.

Comment: 'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),'.split(/[^A-Z]+/)

Comment: @DMoses- The string will always be in this format - "STRING(number), STRING(number), STRING(number), ...." the string part can be integers or characters. the number part will always be integer.

Comment: Should the output be `A B C D E F` or `A, B, C, D, E, F,`?  Your question says one thing and your example output another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
var str = 'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),';
console.log(str.match(/([A-Z])(?=\()/g)); // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eKUMk/).

Updated, for the requirement of 'integers or characters':

```
var str = 'A3(10), aB(20), 34(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),';
console.log(str.match(/([A-Z0-9]+)(?=\()/g)); // ["A3", "B", "34", "D", "E", "F"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eKUMk/2/).

If you'd prefer a simple string, rather than an array:

```
var str = 'A3(10), aB(20), 34(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),';
console.log(str.match(/([A-Z0-9]+)(?=\()/g)).join(' '); // A3 B 34 D E F
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eKUMk/3/).

References:

- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

> split it so that I get all the values outside the parenthesis split by comma

[Remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the parenthesis pairs and then [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),'.replace(/\(\d+\)/g,"").split(/,\s*/);
// ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", ""]
```

To get the output you wanted you might better use a [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) ("word characters before an opening bracket, some none-bracket characters, a closing bracket and a comma"):

```
'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),'.match(/\w+(?=\([^)]*\),)/g);
// ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

or just do a `.match(/[A-Z]+/g)` for simplicity?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string you've supplied is 100% representative of what you are trying to extract data from, you can just do this:

```
var str = 'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),';
str = str.replace(/\(\d+\)/g, '');
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trtyp/1/) showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'A(10), B(20), C(30), D(40), E(10), F(0),';
var sections = str.split(',');
var myRegexp = /^(?:\s+)?([^\(]+)/;
var results = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if(sections[i]){
        var match = myRegexp.exec(sections[i]);
        if(match[1]){
             results[results.length] = match[1];
        }
    }
}
console.log(results); // outputs: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
alert(results.join(' - ')); // alerts: A - B - C - D - E - F
```

Comment: This is definitely the most straight forward approach.